# Problem with JDateChooser, error while getting the date

Tags: java

I'm using JDateChooser, however I can not retrieve the date I enter and always get a null object.

```
dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
Date dateFromDateChooser = dateChooser.getDate();
String dateString = String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", dateFromDateChooser);
System.err.println("IHI date string  " + dateString);
```

That's what I obtain in the console :

```
IHI date string  null-null-null
```

Comment: `dateChooser` is an instance of?

Comment: Generic programming questions should be posted on [so].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `dateChooser.getDate()` returns `null`. You've just instantiated the object `dateChooser`, but never assigned a Date object.

This is the implementation of the method `getDate()` in `JDateChooser.java`

```
/**
 * Returns the date. If the JDateChooser is started with a null date and no
 * date was set by the user, null is returned.
 * 
 * @return the current date
 */
public Date getDate() {
    return dateEditor.getDate();
}
```

Next, the static method `String.format` in your code accepts also `null` for the second parameter, eg:

```
String dateString = String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", null);
System.err.println("IHI date string  " + dateString);
```

Output:

```
IHI date string  null-null-null
```

---

*Based on your code*, a senseless but working example is this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JDateChooser dateChooser = new JDateChooser();
    dateChooser.setDate(new Date());
    Date dateFromDateChooser = dateChooser.getDate();
    String dateString = String.format("%1$td-%1$tm-%1$tY", dateFromDateChooser);
    System.err.println("IHI date string  " + dateString);
}
```

Output:

```
IHI date string  06-05-2015
```

Set a Date instance in your GUI before reading a Date instance or set a default Date instance.

Comment: Sure, today's date. It's a senseless example. You should anter a date in your GUI.

Comment: That  always returns today's date. Suppose that I enter an other date in my graphical inteface. How can I retrieve the right date ??

Comment: Yes I entred an other date in my GUI but the result is always today's date

Comment: Then remove my _example line_: `dateChooser.setDate(new Date());`.

Comment: When I remove it I get the null value that I had before

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23489/discussion-between-a-b-and-nameless).

Comment: your answer did not help me anymore

Comment: @nameless The problem here is you're not setting the date using `.setDate()` after having read it from the GUI. This answer is correct, and its purpose was to show this. [This has been explained to you](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23489/discussion-between-a-b-and-nameless), so you should edit your question to include the code relevant to the part in which you store your inputs from the GUI. Also since this question at least partially helped you narrowing down the problem, it indeed deserves at least an upvote.